# how to check the csv contain a specific column header in ruby using fastercsv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fastercsv

I have a csv file contains values as:

```
"UID","NAME","USERNAME","ROLE","ADDRESS"
12,"Joe","joe_123","A","address1"
13,"Lee","lee_321","U","address2"
```

I need to check existence of column heading `"UID"` and `"USERNAME"` in the csv file. I am using ruby and fastercsv gem.

Please help me how to write this checking using fastercsv. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can read the content of csv file with this:

```
FasterCSV.foreach("path/to/file.csv") do |row|
    # use row here...
  end
```

than you can use header? and headers() methods to determine headers. Vizit http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/ if you need additional information.

Comment: Thank you Ryaz. Now I can use headers() for getting headings